# Why are there darker faces forming a pixelated pattern in my mesh?

Tags: modeling

Why are there darker faces in my mesh. They form some sort of "pixelated"  pattern across faces in my mesh?

[image]

Comment: shift + n maybe ?

Comment: i used the key combination and my problem fixes